# Getting a key from a hashtable without the value in Java

Tags: java, key, hashtable

I have a hashtable like so

```
hashtable = new Hashtable();
```

How can I get a key (any key will do) from the hashtable without knowing a value pair for the key? If I could select a key randomly from the hashtable that would be brilliant but really all I need is to just extract a key from the hashtable.

Comment: The answers below are good for the question you *asked*, but why would you need to know a value to get a key anyway? Do you have the concept of key and value reversed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hashtable.keySet()` will return a set of keys.  To get a random key, use

```
Object[] keys = hashtable.keySet().toArray();
Object key = keys[new Random().nextInt(keys.length)];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
if (!hashtable.isEmpty()) {
   Object firstKey = hashtable.keySet().iterator().next();
   ...
}
```

Aside from this this `Hashtable` methods have the overhead of being synchronized and the class itself is obsolete. Consider using a `Map` from the collections API, such as a `HashMap` or `LinkedHashMap`. Also use generic types rather than raw types to avoid casting.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `keySet()` from the Hashtable.

It will return you the `Collection` of all keys which is going to be empty in your case as you didn't put anything into your Hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

Use hashtable.keys() method to get all keys of the hashtable.